# Help with mean convergence proof for normally distributed random variables

Tags: calculus

I'm reading through a solutions manual that seeks to show that
$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) d x=g(\mu)$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{\theta \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2 \theta^{2}}\right)$ and $g (x ) $ is bounded. The manual makes a jump that I'm having a hard time seeing. We have

$$
\begin{gathered}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) d x=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 x}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \exp \left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right) d x \\ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g\left(\mu+\sigma y\right) \exp \left(\frac{-y^{2}}{z}\right) d y\end{gathered}
$$

And I also know that

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(\frac{y^{2}}{2}\right) d y=1
$$
But I don't know how we can move to the next part of the proof

$$
g(\mu)-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) d x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(g(\mu)-g(\mu+\sigma y)) e^{-y^{2} / 2} dy
$$

Without begging the answer and I also don't know where the extra $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ came from in front of the $g(\mu)$.

In case it's helpful, the rest of the proof is showing the RHS goes to 0 as sigma goes to 0. Still thinking about how that proves what we want but I’m happy to noodle on that a bit longer

Comment: It's not enough that $g$ is bounded, you need that $g$ is continuous as well, otherwise the claim is false. But if $g$ is bounded continuous, then it's a simple consequence of weak convergence.

Comment: Yeah, it's continuous as well, sorry for leaving out that detail

Comment: In that case, it's just weak convergence. Set $Z \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and put $X_n = \mu+n^{-1/2}Z$. Then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $\delta_\mu$. (Easily verified by considering characteristic functions or even Chebyshev's inequality). If we let $X = \mu$ almost surely, then $E[g(X_n)] \to E[g(X)] = g(\mu)$ for any bounded continuous $g$

Comment: Makes sense, my background is more in econ and stats so that approach makes sense to me but I want to understand the book's solution better

Comment: Let $Z \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$. All they've done is write $g(\mu)-E[g(X)] = E[g(\mu)-g(\mu+\sigma Z)]$. And for any function $h$, $$E[h(Z)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int h(x)e^{-x^2/2}dx$$